# Activity Indicator will not go away

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using the following code to show an Activity Indicator while some data is loading. The problem is that when I try to hide it again. The Activity Indicator stays put.  The screen lightens a bit but that is it.

To show it:

```
self.overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3];
    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.activityIndicator.center = self.overlayView.center;
    [self.overlayView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.overlayView];
```

To hide it:

```
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [self.overlayView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Are you working on a UITableViewController or a UIViewController ?

Comment: Its on a UITableViewController with static cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your overlayView to the superview of your tableView :

```
[self.view.superview addSubview:self.overlayView];
```

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't change it.  No matter what I try the UIActivityIndicatorView won't go away.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a combination of stackoverflow questions.  Here is my code to show the UIActivityIndicatorView

```
-(void)loadView {
    [super loadView];    
    self.overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3];
    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.activityIndicator.center = self.overlayView.center;
    [self.overlayView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.overlayView];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];    
}
```

Here is the code to hide it. It looks like putting the code in the loadView event made all the difference.

```
[overlayView removeFromSuperview];
```